# Strange srand behaviour inside for loop; c++

Tags: c++, srand

Just writing a program to shuffle a deck of cards, and got different behaviour depending on whether the RNG was seeded inside or outside of the for loop;
ie.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
  srand(time(0));  
  Card temp = deck[i];
  int toSwap = rand()%52;
  deck[i] = deck[toSwap];
  deck[toSwap] = temp;
}
```

gives the output

```
Nine of Hearts
Ace of Clubs
Two of Clubs
Three of Clubs
Four of Clubs
```

etc, but

```
void DeckOfCards::shuffle()
{
  srand(time(0));  
  for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
  {
  Card temp = deck[i];
  int toSwap = rand()%52;
  deck[i] = deck[toSwap];
  deck[toSwap] = temp;
  }
  currentCard =0;
}
```

leads to

```
Ace of Hearts
Queen of Spades
Four of Hearts
Seven of Clubs
Five of Hearts
```

(the correct functionality).  Anyone know why reseeding the RNG would cause this?

Comment: If it's random, how do you know the first output is incorrect?

Comment: time(0) gives different results - what do you expect?

Comment: No strange behavior here. Move along.. :)

Comment: I can't choose out of the many possible duplicates ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How often should I call srand() in a C++ application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954490/how-often-should-i-call-srand-in-a-c-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As time(NULL) changes only every second, the RNG seed will be the same if the for-loop doesn't take more than a second to complete.

Answer (score 3):

Seed is needed only once if  you need pseudo-randoms. If you call srand many times and if you do it before clock seed changes, then you get same values rather than random. Just seed once at the beginning. You can open other programs(winamp etc..) to get more random values (you need to slow your program ;)  Or making empty loops for random iterations could fix the first program. but you need very big randoms like 2 billions (must be smaller than 4 billion) )

Answer (score 0):

While the others are entirely correct that you don't want to use srand(time(0)) inside a loop because you'll get poor randomness, since you're setting the same seed repeatedly, you may wish to keep that in mind for debugging: if you ever need to be able to "replay" a case, write out the seed into a logfile and allow explicit setting of the seed. Otherwise debugging of applications with random numbers can be rather tricky...

Answer (score 0):

you can use boost posix time instead.

but in all cases if you need to call srand only two times, you can use two different fixed value.

Alternatively I use this function to get time in milli seconds

```
 inline long
    getTimeMs ()
    {
      struct timeval start;
      long mtime;

      gettimeofday (&start, NULL);

      mtime = ((start.tv_sec) * 1000 + start.tv_usec / 1000.0) + 0.5;

      return mtime;
    }
```

regards